# Adding A Word to All Post Titles With the_title Filter Hook

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a "word" to the beginning of all post titles on my WordPress website..

I am using the following code and it's working fine **except** that it also adds the word to menu titles. Can you guys please help in modifying the code so it won't add the word to menu titles?

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title, $id ) {
    return 'My World' . $title ;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: In "the menu"? What do you mean with that? Please keep in mind that we don't have access to your website and so we don't necessarily know what you're talking about. You should be providing as much information / context as possible so we can help out. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It means, this code is adding "My World" in front of menu titles as well. I only want it to be applied on POST TITLES

Comment: What are "menu titles" exactly?

Comment: This is a menu title
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/categories-in-menu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to only add that word to post titles (and not pages, for example), change your code to this:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title, $id ) {
    if ( 'post' == get_post_type($id) )
        return 'My World' . $title ;

    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Basically, we're using the [get_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) function to check that the title belongs to a post and if so then we add the 'My World' text to it, otherwise the function will return the original title.

Personally I would also check that this code only runs on the front-end by using the [is_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) function so post titles are displayed normally on the admin section (*WP Dashboard > Posts > All Posts*):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title, $id ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && 'post' == get_post_type($id) )
        return 'My World' . $title ;

    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Oh, by the way, you may need to redo your menu titles after updating your function. WordPress will not automatically update your saved menu.